# Exclude REst api from Vaadin error handling

Tags: vaadin

I searched multiple hours, maybe i cannot google correctly but i could not find the right answer.

I want to implement some REST Api features to my vaadin full stack application. When i accept all traffic, regardless if authenticated or not, to my rest endpoints it works correctly and i get my rest endpoint result, however, when i want to have them authenticated and i try to access without any session token or anything i immediately get the Vaadin error page/redirection to the login page as i can see in my postman.

I already tried excluding everything from /api in the application config but this did not change anything.

I just want to have the security for my rest endpoints completely separate from the Vaadin Security but i do not want to create another own project for the REST part as i want to use the Services i already created.

Same goes for the login. When i want to login from my rest api i always get some Vaadin html page back with the same JSESSIONID every time. What confuses me even more here is that Postman shows that there is no Set-Cookie header, however i have a JSESSIONID in my cookies tab. This, however, seems to always have the same cookie regardless of whether the cookie should already have reached its timeout.

The security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity
{
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")).authenticated());
        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/**");

        super.configure(http);

        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(web);
    }

}
```

Application config:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig
{
    private final IUserEntityRepository _userRepository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()
    {
        return username ->
                _userRepository.findByEmailOrTelephoneNumberOrNameOrIdentifier(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
                //_userRepository.findByIdentifier(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider()
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvier = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvier.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvier.setPasswordEncoder(CustomPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvier;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception
    {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder CustomPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Edit: As described in the comment, i tried adding a MultiSecurity config, however, all requests to vaadin pages end up in the JwtAuthenticationFilter which should not be the case as only Rest Api calls should get and need this token.

MultiSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiSecurityConfig
{
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class RestApiSecurityConfig
    {
        private final JwtAuthenticationFilter _jwtAuthenticationFilter;
        private final AuthenticationProvider _authenticationProvider;
        private final RestAuthenticationEntryPoint _restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            return http
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/login").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated())
                    .httpBasic(hbc -> hbc.authenticationEntryPoint(_restAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                    .sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authenticationProvider(_authenticationProvider)
                    .addFilterBefore(_jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity
    {
        private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {

            super.configure(http);

            setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
        {
            super.configure(web);
        }
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```
Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
    private final JwtService _jwtService;
    private final ITokenBlackListRepository _blacklistedTokenRepository;
    private final UserDetailsService _userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATIONHEADER);
        final String jwtToken;
        final String identifier;

        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
        {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
        if(_blacklistedTokenRepository.existsByToken(jwtToken))
        {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        identifier = _jwtService.ExtractUsername(jwtToken);

        if(identifier != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)
        {
            UserDetails userDetails = this._userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(identifier);
            //if(!userDetails.isEnabled()) // enable when isEnabled is set to true from email verification
            //{
            //    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            //    return;
            //}

            if(_jwtService.IsTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails))
            {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
            }
        }
        var e = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried setting my application.properties up like this but still the error handling and login for /api paths gets me some html code from vaadin back in postman.

```
vaadin.url-mapping=/ui/*
vaadin.exclude-urls=/api/**
```

Comment: If you access the API you need a different authentication mechanism. Because if you are not logged in you will be redirected to the login page. Or how did you wanted to do the authentication process to access the API?

Comment: Yes i wanted to use the standard spring security authentication mechanism for the rest api part.

Comment: I tried setting up a multisecurity config so that i have my own for everything that goes to /api and the standard vaadin one for the vaadin requests. I can now access the Login Page from Vaadin. When i login, however, even though i am accessing something that does not have /api in front as it is just a vaadin page i end up in the JwtAuthenticationFilter but from my understanding this should not happen as i permit everything going to /**. The code of the MultiSecurityConfig and the JwtAuthenticationFilter are in the original post.